# parent menu with active class when child menu is active

Tags: html, css

I have this header for my website:

http://jsfiddle.net/9n6gj0aa/

how can i make it display with the logo on the left, buttons on the right of the logo and then the menu in the centre under the logo and buttons?

currently the menu is not displaying in the correct place

i tried adding this container:

```
.navigation-container {
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

but that didnt put the menu in the right place, its just moved it down a little

Comment: try scrolling to the right

Comment: i would like the menu to display above that line if possible

Comment: check here - http://jsfiddle.net/9n6gj0aa/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a wrap (where you had the nav container - couldn't find the css) and the following code

```
.logo, .header-buttons{display:inline-block;}
#wrap{margin-top:220px; margin-bottom:15px;display:block;}
```

Comment: thats displaying the menu under the header line - http://jsfiddle.net/9n6gj0aa/1/

Comment: please check the links again